# Problem with c written server displaying a bmp image

Tags: c, hex, bmp

First off, if anyone would like to compile the server and run it

1. go to http://pastebin.com/qPnE3jV0
2. compile and run it
3. go to your browser and type http://localhost:7191/

The function I'm looking at particularly is:

```
void serveHTML (int socket) {

    char *message;
    int i;
    int j;

    //image data
    char bmpheader[54] = {0x42, 0x4D, 0x5A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x24, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x13, 0x0B, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

    char bmpimagedata[36] = {0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x66, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0x07, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x46, 0x00, 0x00};

   message = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                "Content-Type: image/bmp\r\n"
                "Content-Length: 90\r\n";
   printf ("%s\n", message);
   write (socket, message, strlen(message));

   // now send the contents of the web page to be displayed
i=0;
j=0;
while (i < 54) {
    printf("%c", bmpheader[i]);
    write (socket, &bmpheader[i], 1);
    i++;
}
while (j < 36) {
    printf("%c", bmpimagedata[j]);
    write (socket, &bmpimagedata[j], 1);
    j++;
}


}
```

- What I've done here is stored the hex
  data of a 3x3 bmp file into two
  arrays (for convenience of
  modification) the header and the
  image data. I **try** to get it to
  serve this bmp on a web browser.
  However it fails.
- I've placed printf's all over the
  place to print what the server is
  spitting out... however I think I'm
  missing something (possibly a
  footer?).

Any help would be appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out as to why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers need to end with *two* `\r\n` - Append `\r\n` to your `message` constant.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! So it was that little bastard all along.

Answer (score 0):

A few points:

1. Don't use such bizarre code to write out the arrays. Just use plain `write(socket, bmpheader, sizeof bmpheader);` and the same for the data.
2. Inspect the return value of `write()`; it can fail.

Comment: I've looked at all the writes (except the bmp ones) and they seem to be giving me what I want.